# Bash script - delete duplicates

Tags: linux, bash

I need to extract name from a file and delete duplicates.

output.txt:

```
Server001-1
Server001-2
Server001-3
Server001-4
Server002-1
Server002-2
Server003-1
Server003-2
Server003-3
```

I need to only have output as follow.

```
Server001-1
Server002-1
Server003-1
```

So, only print first server for every server group (Server00*) and delete the rest in that group.

Comment: Do you want the first one in the order that they appear, or the lowest number in the second part?

Comment: Can you post a script that shows what you tried?

Comment: Can you maybe just `grep -e '-1$'`?

Answer (score 0):

try simply with awk:

```
awk -F"-" '!a[$1]++'  Input_file
```

**Explanation**: Making a field separator as - and then creating an array named a whose index is current line's 1st field and checking here a condition !a[$1] means it will check if current line's 1st field doesn't have any presence in array a then do a print of that line and then ++ means it will create that specific line's 1st field's occurrence value to 1 in array a so next time that line will not be printed.

Comment: Request to down vote person that I have added explanation with edited solution now, could you please remove if you think it is feasible now?

Comment: Looks better now, would be good to see you post correct, tested answers with an explanation in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F- 'dat[$1]=="" { dat[$1]=$0 } END { for (i in dat) {print dat[i]}}' filename
```

result:

```
Server001-1
Server002-1
Server003-1
```

Create an array keyed on the first space delimited piece of data storing the complete line only when there are no other entries in that array entry. This will ensure that only the first unique entry is stored. Loop through the array and print

Answer (score 0):

Simple GNU ***datamash*** solution:

```
datamash -t'-' -g1 first 2 <file
```

- `-t'-'` - field separator
- `-g1` - group lines by the 1st field
- `first 2` - get only first value of the 2 field for each group. Can be also changed to `min 2` operation

The output:

```
Server001-1
Server002-1
Server003-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned the string format as `Server00*`, you can simply use this one :

```
grep -E "Server\d+-1" file
```

`Server\d+` for cases Server1000, Server100000 etc

or even

```
grep  '[-]1$' file
```

Output for both :

```
Server001-1
Server002-1
Server003-1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way just 1 command line to get general unique result:

`nin output.txt nul "^(\w+)-\d+" -u -w`

Explanation:

- `nul` is a non-existing Windows file like `/dev/null` on Linux.
- `-u` to get unique result, `-w` to output whole lines. Ignore case ? use `-i`.
- `"^(\w+)-\d+"` is the same Regex syntax in `C++`/`C#`/`Java`/`Scala`, etc.
- Save to file ? `nin output.txt nul "^(\w+)-\d+" -u -w > result.txt`
- Save to file with summary info ? `nin output.txt nul "^(\w+)-\d+" -u -w -I > result.txt`
- Future automation with `nin.exe` : Result count = return value `%ERRORLEVEL%`

`nin.exe` / `nin.gcc*` is a single portable exe tool to get **difference** or **intersection** keys/lines between `2 files` or `a pipe and a file`. See my open project `tools` directory of https://github.com/qualiu/msr. 
And you can also see colorful built-in usage/examples: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/nin-Windows.html

[image: Get unique key set or line set]